# How can I use a SQL MERGE Statement in VBA access?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have been trying to use the MERGE statement in my Access application.  When I use the following code (simplified for readability):

```
dim strSqlMerge as string
strSqlMerge = "MERGE TargeTable AS T USING SourceTable as S " & _
" ON T.PrimaryKeyColumn = S.PrimaryKeyColumn " & _
" WHEN MATCHED AND PrimaryKeyColumn = 'hardcodedvalue' THEN " & _
" UPDATE SET T.Column1 = S.Column1, T.Column2 = S.Column2, ..."

Currentdb.Execute strSqlMerge
```

I get the error 3078: The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'MERGE TargeTable AS T USING SourceTable as S ...'
Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Access does not implement MERGE, search here for Access Upsert

Comment: ANd frankly MERGE is a bd idea even in SQL Server, see https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Answer (score 1):

Access does not support MERGE. That construct exists in T-SQL (SQL Server) and other SQL dialects, but not in Access SQL.

Comment: OK I see you have edited my reply. But MERGE is not a T-SQL construct. It exists in ANSI SQL and some other databases implement it too (and it is not called T-SQL in those databases).